# Nginx limit requests by IP range / subnet, not a single IP

Tags: nginx

I can limit the rate of incoming connections from particular IP by using limit_conn_zone directive. But what if I want to set the zone not to just $remote_addr (which will give me separate limits for every single IP address in the world), but to the /16 subnet of the $remote_addr?

Answer (score 1):

The [`limit_conn_zone`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html#limit_conn_zone)  can apply limits based on any key and doesn't require that the key is an IP-address; you're not limited to `$remote_addr` and you can use `$remote_subnet`.

In short your problem then becomes:  there is no easily used pre-defined variable `$remote_subnet` that can be used as key for the [ngx_http_limit_conn_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) and/or [ngx_http_limit_req_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html).

The problem with trying to define  a subnet to use as a key is that with the abolishment of [A/B/C classful network addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network)  and the introduction of [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) applications including  nginx have no idea  what actual subnet a particular remote IP-address belongs to. Not for IPv4 addresses and certainly not for IPv6 addresses.

Also there is also no nginx setting that says *"always assume the subnet mask to be `/some_value` to calculate a synthetic `$remote_subnet` value which `$remote_addr` should belong to"* for a dumb approach.

That means you have to define such a function and perform that calculation yourself.

As far as I know nginx doesn't have such native support for calculations of any kind and taking an IP address and properly calculating for a given subnet mask the network ID will probably require using the nginx lua module and a bit of custom coding.

Alternatively for large enough subnets you could consider hardcoding a lookup table with for example the [geo module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html).

```
# Use the geo module lookup a synthetic $remote_subnet value
geo $remote_addr $remote_subnet {
    0.0.0.0/8     0.0.0.0;
    1.0.0.0/8     1.0.0.0;
    2.0.0.0/9     2.0.0.0;
    2.128.0.0/9   2.128.0.0;
    3.0.0.0/8     3.0.0.0;
    4.0.0.0/8     4.0.0.0;
    5.0.0.0/8     5.0.0.0;
    6.0.0.0/8     6.0.0.0;
    7.0.0.0/8     7.0.0.0;
    8.0.0.0/8     8.0.0.0;
    9.0.0.0/8     9.0.0.0;
    10.0.0.0/8   10.0.0.0;
    11.0.0.0/8   11.0.0.0;
    ...
}


# Requests with an empty $remote_subnet will not be accounted

limit_conn_zone $remote_subnet  zone=persubnet:10m;


server {
    ...
    limit_conn persubnet 10;
}
```